# Convolution property of Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, convolution, signal-processing

I have a signal $$ x(t) = \frac{1}{T} e^{- \frac{t}{T} } u(t) $$ and I know his Fourier transform $$ X(f) = \frac{1}{1+ i 2\pi f T } $$ and I have to find $$ z(t) = x(t) \circledast x(t) $$ using convolution property or in time domain and after I have to calculate $$ Z(f) $$. I found easily that $$ Z(f) = [ \frac{1}{1+ i 2 \pi T } ] ^{2} $$ that’s because I studied that the Fourier transform of $$ z(t) = x(t) \circledast x(t) $$ is $$ Z(f) = X(f) \cdot X(f) $$. Now I don’t know how to find z(t). I tried to anti transform but I didn’t obtain a result similar of my book :/ the result should be $$ \frac{i}{2 \pi T } (- i 2 \pi T ) \frac{1}{T} e^{\frac{-t}{T}} u(t) $$ and it appears to have been applied derivative property but I don’t know why. Thank you so much !

Comment: So what is the derivative of $X(f)$ with respect to $f$?

Comment: Probably i didn’t understand you question , but the Fourier transform of derivative of X(f) should be $$ - i 2 \pi t x(t) $$

Comment: Take the derivate of $X(f)$ with respect to $f$ and compare that to $Z(f)$.

Comment: I obtained that the derivative of $$ X(f) $$ is $$ \frac{-1 - i 2 \pi T }{[ 1+i 2 \pi f T ] ^{2}} $$

Comment: So you have two errors: 1) Your expression for $Z(f)$ in your question is missing the $f$ in the denominator. 2) Your derivative of $X(f)$ shouldn't have the $-1$ term in the numerator.

Comment: You’re right ! I forgot to write f in the denominator of Z(f) and I made a (big ) mistake on the derivative. $$ X’(f) = \frac { - i 2 \pi  f}{[1 + i 2 \pi f T]^{2}} $$ so i obtained that $$ X’(f) = -i 2 \pi f [ Z(f) ] $$

Comment: But I don’t understand the link with z(t)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107303/discussion-between-andy-walls-and-elena-martini).

Answer (score 1):

You need to work with the frequency derivative property
$$-itx(t) \longleftrightarrow \frac{dX(\omega)}{d\omega}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{dX(f)}{df},$$
with $\omega=2\pi f$ and '$\longleftrightarrow$' tying the Fourier transform pair. Work on the derivative:
$$-itx(t) \longleftrightarrow \frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{d}{df}\left(\frac{1}{1+i2\pi fT}\right)$$
$$-itx(t) \longleftrightarrow -\frac{iT}{(1+i2\pi fT)^2}.$$
Now modify the pair using the linearity property until you get $Z(f)$ on the right-hand side:
$$-itx(t) \longleftrightarrow -\frac{i T}{(1+i2\pi fT)^2}$$
$$\frac{t}{T}x(t) \longleftrightarrow \frac{1}{(1+i2\pi fT)^2}$$
and therefore
$$z(t)=\frac{t}{T}x(t)=\frac{1}{T^2}te^{-\frac{t}{T}}u(t).$$
This should be the right answer. I believe you have some typos in your proposed book solution, since the self-convolution of a causal exponential $e^{-at}u(t)$, $a>0$, is equal to $te^{-at}u(t)$, as you can now easily verify using similar procedure :)